# Getting an error : Missing Required Command Line Arguments: -ism <ISM file>

Tags: vbscript, installshield, wsh

I'm building an installer using script file. I'm executing following command :

```
C:\windows\system32\cscript.exe "%WSR%\InstallShield\BuildInstalls.vbs" -ism "C:\InstallShield\Windows\xyz.ism" -verbose Build -version 1.1.1 -skipcopy -Platform Win32 -web
```

But I'm getting following error :

> Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8 Copyright (C) Microsoft
>   Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Setup Output Log File:
>   InstallShield\BuildInstalls.vbs_3_25_2016_13_3.out
>   InstallBuild ERROR:
>   Missing Required Command Line Arguments:  -ism

ISM file is also present at proper location and all parameters are correct. But still I'm getting this error. So where I'm doing the mistake ?

Comment: Show the actual script, particularly that part that is raising the error. If it's a long script, reduce it to a smaller sample that still demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `BuildInstalls.vbs` treats its parameters from command line using standard [`Arguments` Property (WScript Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2b05k8s(v=vs.84).aspx) and its inferior collections [`WshUnnamed` Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah2hawwc(v=vs.84).aspx) and [`WshNamed` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6y04sbb(v=vs.84).aspx), then as per [Working with Command-Line Arguments](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156618.aspx) article:

> The `WshNamed` filtered collection contains the two named arguments.
>   Named arguments are arguments that consist of two parts: a name and a
>   value. The name must be prefaced with a forward slash, and a colon
>   must separate the name from the value. The **slash prefix and the
>   colon separator are fixed and cannot be changed**. For example, you
>   cannot use a hyphen in place of the slash; the following command will
>   not pass Server as a named argument; instead, it will treat
>   -Server:atl-dc-01 as the value of a single unnamed argument

Therefore, use `/ism:"C:\InstallShield\Windows\xyz.ism"` parameter.

If `BuildInstalls.vbs` is not your own work, maybe it accepts `/help`, `/H`, `/?` or alike option?